# Overleaf template for IEEE journals

Tags: formatting, ieee, latex

The Overleaf website has a LaTeX template IEEE Transactions. Does it fully support the format as desired by IEEE?

Comment: Which template do you exactly mean?!

Comment: Actually i am preparing a research paper for IEEE jounral. I used overleaf online tool which enables to generate Latex documents. A predefined templates is given there. I just want to know does it follow the guidelines given IEEE for document format.

Comment: Which is faster? a) download the template from the IEEE; b) find the template somewhere else, ask on Stack Exchange if it's the right one, wait for a reply?

Comment: @ David Richerby, Overleaf provides simultaneous editing amoung co-authors. I just wanted to conform about its format. Now I got to know that one may directly upload his manuscripts from Overleaf to ScholarOne sumbmission website. You may check it at ScholarOne website. Now you tell, which is faster and better? ;)

Answer (score 2):

According to Overleaf, **yes**. The top of their [gallery page](https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/academic-journal) states:

> Here we provide a selection of academic journal templates for articles and papers which automatically format your manuscripts in the style required for submission to that journal.

For what it is worth, the IEEEtran template looks identical to the one that one would [download from the IEEE](https://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/author_templates.html) for the Computer Society. Given how easy it is for Overleaf to keep the template file up to date and the loss of users they may suffer from providing invalid templates, there isn't really a strong reason to suspect that they do not have the correct version for use there.

Answer (score 1):

These are the templates tagged as IEEE Official: https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/ieee-official, but I also recommend to download the latest LaTeX template from IEEE's website and upload it to Overleaf as a zip.